# Is there any way to know what is the right form for the values of parameters in a SOAP API?

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap

For example I have found this free web service:

http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx

and I want to test my client, but I don't know what input parameters I should specify for my request.

This happens with a number of APIs that I want to test with. Is there any way to find out what possible values could be, since there is no documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You've got several options here.

If you've installed Visual Studio you can use WCF Test Client to test the API.

More information on WCF Test Client [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe)

Alternatively you can use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org) by SmartBear.

Most of the time you just specify the URL of the service and it will give you a list of all the available methods and what inputs they expect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by the link you've submitted, there is a document with the parameters explained: http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?op=ConvertTemp

Request:

```
POST /ConvertTemperature.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertTemp"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConvertTemp xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <Temperature>double</Temperature>
      <FromUnit>degreeCelsius or degreeFahrenheit or degreeRankine or degreeReaumur or kelvin</FromUnit>
      <ToUnit>degreeCelsius or degreeFahrenheit or degreeRankine or degreeReaumur or kelvin</ToUnit>
    </ConvertTemp>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

`Temperature`, `FromUnit` and `ToUnit` are the request/input parameters.

Considering the server is asmx-based, this URL should give you the full schema: http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?wsdl

Hope I understood your question correctly.

P.S. It's not usually a good idea to test your code (e.g. auto-test) against a live (or production) system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why it's not a good idea to test code on a live system? Where should I test it against?

Comment: What we usually do is a mock of the system that you'd like to test against within our dev server. It can be a static file response, nothing too complex. Just to make sure that the expected responses can be treated correctly by the client. Check this link fore more info: https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/rest-service-mocking.html